# Magento 2 without user login add to cart ajax not working with redis session

Tags: ajax, redis, magento2

I have Issue with Magento version. 2.2.0 with integration of redis session.

In my magento 2.2.0 Redis Session is enabled , Now when user is not logged in(Guest User) to the system and try to add the product to cart , its not working.

Ajax add to cart call successfully without any error but product is not adding cart.

Any clue for this issue ? Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: did u check the request in the console? and is this happening for all products? is it working when user is logged in ?

Comment: @Ash-b Yes. This happening for all product. when user login it is working.

Comment: did you check the redis-log file?

Comment: @Ash-b Yes. There is no found issue in redis-log file.